# WordPress admin redirect conundrum

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I feel stupid for trying this and not realising what would happen.

Anyway.

Using the wp_redirect function...

```
if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    $url = "https://example.com";
    wp_redirect( $url );
}
```

...I want anyone with the role of 'administrator' to be redirected to the homepage when they login. Seems easy enough.

But the problem is that any consequent attempt to go to WP admin (not just after they login, but any time) will result in the administrator being redirected to the homepage effectively 'locking' them out of WP admin.

So I guess my question is, is it possible to redirect an administrator to the homepage when they login, but only immediately after they login? And any consequent attempt to go to /wp-admin/ would let them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve your problem.You can add this code in functions.php.I tested and confirmed its working for me.

```
    function admin_redirection_page() {

      return 'https://example.com';
    }

    add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_redirection_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fire the above code in hook `wp_login`.

Example:

```
function your_function() {
    $url = "https://example.com";
    wp_redirect( $url );
    die();
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
```

Also we have use `die()` whenever we want to redirect.

Thank You